# How to extract all pattern matches from one line into a list

Tags: sed

The goal is to extract all strings matching a pattern from one line of text and to display the results as a list.

For instance:

```
pattern="as[^\',]+?\.bin"
line="[['Directory of boot:/', '', '81 -rwx 110665728 17:33:44 Mar 25 2018 asa992-smp-k8.bin', '82 -rwx 32738292 17:33:44 Mar 25 2018 asdm-79247.bin', '83 -rwx 59123840 17:33:44 Mar 25 2018 asa-restapi-132300-lfbff-k8.SPA', '', '3 file(s) total size: 202527860 bytes', '534495232 bytes total (331800576 bytes free/62% free)']]"
```

I tried:

```
echo $line | sed -E "s|.* (${pattern}).*|\1|g"
asdm-79247.bin
```

I expect:

```
asa992-smp-k8.bin
asdm-79247.bin
```

Any suggestion?

If it is not possible with sed, I'm open to any other tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with egrep -o

```
echo $line | egrep -o "as[-_A-Za-z0-9]*.bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
pattern=as[^\',]+?\.bin
sed -E '/'"${pattern}"'/!d;s//\n&\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;P;D' file
```

This deletes any lines that do not contain the pattern, otherwise it surrounds the pattern by newlines, deletes upto and including the first newline, prints the string matching the pattern, deletes the pattern and the following newline and repeats.